# XSLT to alphabetize XML

Tags: xslt, schema

I have about 10 xml schemas that I have to clean up by alphabetizing the elements/types. I googled for a while and found someone's solution,

[Here](http://blog.timothylux.com/2009/05/how-to-alphabetize-xml-elements-using.html)

which doesn't work for me for whatever reason (it skips from xsd:schema straight to xsd:comlplexType name=Account). 
Here is the simplist example, as you can see the first 10 or so elements are in order, but when the developer added 2 new fields they are out of order (crossRef and ID). I want to make sure that CrossRef and ID are alphabetized not only in the sequence when defined as part of the Account object, but also, if they were defined as their own types separately (these two fields aren't but the rest are) that their definitions would also be alphabetized with the rest of the definitions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsd:schema targetNamespace="####" xmlns="####" xmlns:lms.base="####/base" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:import namespace="###/base" schemaLocation="Base.xsd" />

<xsd:element name="Account" type="Account" />

<xsd:complexType name="Account" >

    <xsd:complexContent >
        <xsd:extension base="lms.base:ExtensionBase">
            <xsd:sequence >
                <xsd:element name="Address" type="lms.base:Address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" />       
                <xsd:element name="BusinessSegment" type="lms.base:BusinessSegment" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1" />
                <xsd:element name="Name" type="AccountName" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1" />
                <xsd:element name="Number" type="AccountNumber" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1" />
                <xsd:element name="Office" type="AccountOffice" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1" />
                <xsd:element name="Status" type="AccountStatus" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1" />
                <xsd:element name="UWMemo" type="lms.base:UWMemo" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1" />
      <xsd:element name="CrossRef" type="lms.base:string-minLength" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="ID" type="xsd:long" />
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>       
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="AccountID">
    <xsd:restriction base="lms.base:ID" />
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="AccountName">
    <xsd:restriction base="lms.base:string-minLength" />
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="AccountNumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="lms.base:string-minLength" />
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="AccountStatus">
    <xsd:restriction base="lms.base:string-minLength">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Not_Assigned" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Active" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Inactive" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Targeted/Prospect" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Lost" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Submission Declined" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Terminated" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Claim" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Watch List" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="H.O. Hold/Suspend" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Infrequent" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="AccountOffice">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="lms.base:Value"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Is this something you want to do one time? Every time you commit to source control? Daily?   The solutions proposed will probably vary base on how frequent you want to do this.

Comment: I'd like to run it periodically. I don't see how the frequency of running a XSLT would alter it's design...

Comment: Could you, please, provide the exact XML document you want to be ordered, describe what has to be ordered by which sort key and also provide the expected correct result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sort everything by `name` attribute, right? In that case, this might work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

    <!-- Sort child elements by name, if any child has one -->
    <xsl:template match="*[*/@name]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|text()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity template for everything else -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are a genius. That works perfectly. May I buy you a beer?